# How to install ubuntu 14.10 on flash drive

Tags: usb, live-cd

How to install ubuntu 14.10 on a 16gb usb flash drive. I want to install it, as if it were the hard drive, not live cd, because my hard drive is broken.

Comment: You'll need another USB drive from which to run the installation.

Answer (score 1):

I made a bootable flashdrive using a windows netbook and the program at [this webpage](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).
This worked great for me. I have used it to install on a few computers as well as running Ubuntu Live from the stick itself.